# Why is the title font smaller than chapter/part fonts in the book class?

Tags: fontsize, book-design

This is not really a very important question, but I have noticed that the default "Book" class  has a relatively normal-sized font for the title page, which contains the title of the book and the name of the author(s), but the font for a part or a chapter heading is *huge*. It is almost as if the title is inconsequential, and only the titles of the chapters are important. Is there a stylistic reason that this is the default? From a design perspective, is this normal (for published books, say)?

Comment: The title page should not be confused with the cover. The title page is the page inside the book which repeats the title from the cover together with the author and sometimes includes more detail, and usually features the publisher and address at the bottom, too. I've always assumed this was why. On the other hand, I think books tend to use not-terribly-huge fonts for the chapter titles, too. [`\chapter` uses both `\Huge` and bold; the title just uses `\LARGE`. To some extent, the degree of difference will be font-dependent, of course.]

Comment: not all publishers agree with the style used for the `book` class.  (for example, the heading fonts for `amsbook` are considerably more modest.)  but it's also true that at least some publishers use the generated title page only for identification during production, and create a separate title page for the published book.  if the output from the latex compilation is to be the final published version, by all means consider designing a special title page instead of using the default.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! They could be made to be answers, though. I think the difference between the title page and the cover is what I really needed to realize.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about design and also really only answerable by the original author of LaTeX.